# Symfony 5 - Easy Admin 3: Heavy load on AssociationField when the associated entity have so many data

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5, easyadmin, easyadmin3

I have the following CrudController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Admin\Core;

use App\Entity\Core\Role;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\AbstractCrudController;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\AssociationField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\ChoiceField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\IntegerField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\SlugField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\TextEditorField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\TextField;

class RoleCrudController extends AbstractCrudController
{
    public static function getEntityFqcn(): string
    {
        return Role::class;
    }

    public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
    {
        return [
            TextField::new('name', 'Name')
                ->setRequired(true)
                ->setMaxLength(255)
                ->setHelp('The role name, prefix with: ROLE_'),
            SlugField::new('systemName', 'System Name')
                ->setRequired(true)
                ->setTargetFieldName('name')->setFormattedValue(function ($value) {
                    return strtoupper($value);
                }),
            TextEditorField::new('description', 'Description'),
            IntegerField::new('level', 'Role Level')->setHelp('Provide the role level'),
            AssociationField::new('subsOfRole', 'Parent Role'),
            ChoiceField::new('type', 'Role Relation Type')
                ->setChoices([
                    'User' => 1,
                    'Job Title' => 2,
                    'Unit' => 3,
                    'Office' => 4,
                    'Echelon' => 5,
                    'Office Type' => 6,
                    'user Group' => 7,
                    'Job Title + Unit' => 8,
                    'Job Title + Office' => 9,
                    'Job Title + Unit + Office' => 10,
                    'Job Title + Unit + Office Type' => 11
                ])
                ->setRequired(true),
            AssociationField::new('users', 'Users')
                ->setHelp('Must be filled when you choose User as Role Relation Type')
                ->hideOnIndex(),
            AssociationField::new('groups', 'Groups')
                ->setHelp('Must be filled when you choose Group as Role Relation Type')
                ->hideOnIndex(),
            AssociationField::new('jobTitles', 'Job Title')
                ->hideOnIndex(),
            AssociationField::new('units', 'Unit')
                ->hideOnIndex(),
            AssociationField::new('offices', 'Offices')
                ->hideOnIndex(),
            AssociationField::new('echelons', 'Echelons')
                ->hideOnIndex(),
            AssociationField::new('officeTypes', 'Office Types')
                ->hideOnIndex(),
        ];
    }
}
```

It runs well when we have small data, but when we test with tens of thousands data to User Entity/ other related entity, the CRUD page is so slow.

Is there any method to change the way associationField work? Or to improve the performance on user side (browser)?

**Context:**
I use Symfony 5.3.9 and EasyAdmin 3.5.10 which is the latest version when I write this

Thank you

Comment: Have you looked into [autocomplete](https://github.com/EasyCorp/EasyAdminBundle/blob/v3.5.10/src/Field/AssociationField.php#L50)? So that the data is limited by a user filtered subset, instead of all the records as a select element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Will B., I checked the [autocomplete](https://github.com/EasyCorp/EasyAdminBundle/blob/v3.5.10/src/Field/AssociationField.php#L50) feature and tried it. That was the solution.

My previous code became like (see the **->autocomplete()** implementation):

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Admin\Core;

use App\Entity\Core\Role;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\AbstractCrudController;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\AssociationField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\ChoiceField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\IntegerField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\SlugField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\TextEditorField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\TextField;

class RoleCrudController extends AbstractCrudController
{
    public static function getEntityFqcn(): string
    {
        return Role::class;
    }

    public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
    {
        return [
            TextField::new('name', 'Name')
                ->setRequired(true)
                ->setMaxLength(255)
                ->setHelp('The role name, prefix with: ROLE_'),
            SlugField::new('systemName', 'System Name')
                ->setRequired(true)
                ->setTargetFieldName('name')->setFormattedValue(function ($value) {
                    return strtoupper($value);
                }),
            TextEditorField::new('description', 'Description'),
            IntegerField::new('level', 'Role Level')->setHelp('Provide the role level'),
            AssociationField::new('subsOfRole', 'Parent Role')
                ->autocomplete(),
            ChoiceField::new('type', 'Role Relation Type')
                ->setChoices([
                    'User' => 1,
                    'Job Title' => 2,
                    'Unit' => 3,
                    'Office' => 4,
                    'Echelon' => 5,
                    'Office Type' => 6,
                    'user Group' => 7,
                    'Job Title + Unit' => 8,
                    'Job Title + Office' => 9,
                    'Job Title + Unit + Office' => 10,
                    'Job Title + Unit + Office Type' => 11
                ])
                ->setRequired(true),
            AssociationField::new('users', 'Users')
                ->autocomplete()
                ->setHelp('Must be filled when you choose User as Role Relation Type')
                ->hideOnIndex(),
            AssociationField::new('groups', 'Groups')
                ->autocomplete()
                ->setHelp('Must be filled when you choose Group as Role Relation Type')
                ->hideOnIndex(),
            AssociationField::new('jobTitles', 'Job Title')
                ->autocomplete()
                ->hideOnIndex(),
            AssociationField::new('units', 'Unit')
                ->autocomplete()
                ->hideOnIndex(),
            AssociationField::new('offices', 'Offices')
                ->autocomplete()
                ->hideOnIndex(),
            AssociationField::new('echelons', 'Echelons')
                ->autocomplete()
                ->hideOnIndex(),
            AssociationField::new('officeTypes', 'Office Types')
                ->autocomplete()
                ->hideOnIndex(),
        ];
    }
}
```

and now the load is good.

Thank you